# Symfony2 dev environment works, prod environment gives 404 error

Tags: php, symfony

I have recently successfully installed Symfony2 on my machine.

I can access `http:/localhost/app_dev.php` (dev environment)

However, when I try to access the prod environment:

`http:/localhost/app.php`

I get the following error message in the browser:

> **Oops! An Error Occurred**
>
> The server returned a "404 Not Found".
>   Something is broken. Please e-mail us at [email] and let us know what
>   you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as
>   possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

I have checked the obvious: The file app.php does exist in the same folder as app_dev.php - so I don't know whats causing this.

Does anyone have a solution to fix this?

**[[Edit]]**

I have cleared the cache by typing: `sudo php app/console cache:clear env=prod no-debug` as recommended. I now get a blank screen. Worryingly, there are no error messages logged in app/logs/prod.log, so I have not got the faintest idea as to what is wrong (prod environment still works just fine).

Contents of my app/config/routing.yml file:

```
### fos routing, remove later
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile

###


# Internal routing configuration to handle ESI
#_internal:
#   resource: "@FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/routing/internal.xml"
#   prefix:   /_internal
```

Here is my app/config/routing_dev.yml file

```
_welcome:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:index }

_demo_secured:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/SecuredController.php"
    type:     annotation

_demo:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/DemoController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /demo

_assetic:
    resource: .
    type:     assetic

_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_configurator:
    resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
    prefix:   /_configurator

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

I just noticed that I **DO NOT** have a routing_prod.yml**

(alarm bells ringing) - does Symfony2 not ship with a production routing config file?

My Apache configuration file content is shown below:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/symfony/web
    ServerName localhost

    # Custom log file
    Loglevel warn
    ErrorLog  /path/localhost.error.log
    CustomLog /path/localhost.access.log combined

    <Directory /path/to/symfony/web>
        AllowOverride None
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**[[Further Details]]**

Contents of app/logs/prod.log

> [2012-08-10 18:10:38] security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an
>   anonymous Token [] [] [2012-08-10 18:10:38] request.ERROR:
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route
>   found for "GET /" (uncaught exception) at
>   /path/to/symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/EventListener/RouterListener.php
>   line 83 [] []

Comment: Could you paste your `app/config/routing.yml`?

Comment: And also `routing_dev.yml` and `routing_prod.yml`. I also think you should check `access.log` and `error.log` of your web-server. And also, please, attach your web-server virtual host configuration.

Comment: Its okay if there is no `routing_prod.yml`.  It means that it will pick `routing.yml`

Comment: You could also try to manually remove the cache directories (`rm -rf app/cache/*`) and run `app/console router:debug` to see exactly which routes have been registered.

Comment: Im having the same problem, now im at the blank page with no errors like you, so did you found any solution for this?

Comment: I've fixed my problem by creating a routing_prod.yml with _main: resource: routing.yml.

Answer (score 41):

Have you turned on the production environment and cleared the cache?
Run the console and do this:

```
app/console --env=prod cache:clear
```

Comment: If you use `symfony` to generate the project you might try `bin/console` instead of `app/console`

Comment: it's recommended to directly remove the cache directory by hand:
(when in the symfony project directory) $ rm -rf app/cache

Answer (score 12):

I think I had a similar problem. I believe warming up the cache solved my instance if it.

```
php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug
```

Comment: +1 This helped me get around one of those annoying dev works, prod WSOD situations.

Answer (score 4):

Having recently installed Symfony 2.2 I ran into this issue too but it's actually the normal behavior. Meaning out of the box Symfony 2.x (as of this writing) doesn't ship with any routes/content for 
the production environment.

In your case it looks you installed the Friends of Symfony bundle, which did setup some routes in your production route (`routing.yml`), but at a glance none of the routes seem to be targeting the root of your production environment i.e. `http:/localhost/app.php/` so the 404 is probably expected. I can't be *totally* sure though since it's importing routes so the details are obscured. A great way to check your routes is to read up on [Visualizing & Debugging Routes](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/routing.html#visualizing-debugging-routes) where you can learn about the `app/console router:debug` CLI command.

`routing.yml` is the default place for routes in your production environment (meaning `routing_prod.yml` isn't a thing). You'll notice `routing_dev.yml` imports `routing.yml`. That means that everything that you put in production is (out of the box) accesible in the development. The demo content you see is exclusive to the dev environment so that's why you're not seeing it in the production. Feel free to move some stuff around to suite your needs but it's generally a good idea for the dev to import the production but not vice versa.

Any time you want to test out the changes in your production you'll want to clear your cache as @tolgap recommends. The production environment leans heavily on the precompiled cache, so that command will force your production cache to refresh. The dev environment is always refreshing it's cache. Understanding this is crucial to working with Symfony. Though the Book on Symfony.org is a great entry point it doesn't exactly drive home this point about the subtitles of caching and workflow. I was definitely confused for a minute before I realized the relationship between `routing.yml` and `routing_dev.yml` and the soft caching of the dev versus the hard caching of the production.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the solution @gilden gave in his comment; it works.

I ran `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` instead of `rm -rf app/cache/*`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that nobody told you:
you have no route for / on the prod environment.

write this in app/config/routing.yml

```
  _welcome:
 pattern:  /
 defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:index }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install APC for your local server, and everything will work in prod mod for you.
Also try to hit correct database in parameters.yml, because dev is adding DATABASENAME_dev.

Answer (score 2):

Today I had the same problem and tried various solutions. Until I remembered that it is important to have the mod_rewrite apache service enabled. To do this run the following command (on Ubuntu)

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

And then restart the server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I hope that someone can be helpful.
Regards!

Comment: This happened to me when using the docker php7.0-apache image! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My symfony cache folder was not writable. It worked when i made the cache complete directory and its files as writable.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 .
```

Answer (score 0):

When this problem occurs, just add a .htaccess in your public dir. Here is an example:

```html
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options +FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/index" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/index.php" but be rewritten to "/index.php/index".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/index.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -2):

(Agrega esto dentro del archivo routing_dev.yml) Add this in routing_dev.yml

```
_wellcome:
    pattern: /
    defaults: { _controller:AppBundle:Default:index }
```