# Symfony Routing only works in debug mode

Tags: symfony, controller, routes, yaml

I try to add an route to my symfony Projekt. But it doesnt work.

My routing.yml:

```
app:
resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
type: annotation

login:
path:     /login
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Login:index }
```

My LoginController.php:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('login/index.html.twig', [
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        ]);
    }
}
```

When i try to load this page, i become "The server returned a "404 Not Found"."

But when i open app.php and change this line:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

to this one:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

it works.

Why, i have to set debug true, to load this page?

When i use app_dev.php/login all works fine. No error appears. Site will be loaded.

I have def. changed the routing.yml file. not the routing_dev.yml!

Thank you !!

Comment: Maybe turn prod mode and clear cache `app/console --env=prod cache:clear`  Did you find: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862468/symfony2-dev-environment-works-prod-environment-gives-404-error

Comment: yes thank you. Clear cache fix it...